# Why does busy-wait of less than 15ms are inconsistent?

Tags: java, multithreading, busy-waiting, busy-loop

I am doing simulation project where i have hundred of CPU-Bound jobs running for 10 to 50 milliseconds. The Job is a Runnable object with specified running-time for which the job will keep CPU busy. There are 10 threads waiting in a thread pool for job arrival. I set request rate to 40 requests per second and all jobs running-time is set to 10ms. But results are so much terrible . All jobs run for at least 15ms. There is no job that runs for 10 ms. i test the experiment with jobs at 15ms and i got correct result. Why does 10ms jobs run for atleast 15ms?(I am using WINDOWS8).

```
public class CpuBoundJob implements Runnable {
long runningTime
     public CpuBoundJob(long runningTime) {
        this.runningTime=runningTime;
          }
    @Override
    public void run() {

         long timeToWait = this.runningTime;
         long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         while(startTime + timeToWait > System.currentTimeMillis());
}
}
```

Comment: The resolution of your system timer is probably 15ms. You could try [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--), but it might not have any more resolution. The linked Javadoc says (in part) *no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of `currentTimeMillis()`.*

Answer (score 1):

On many systems (Windows specifically, IIRC), `System.currentTimeMillis()` is backed by a clock that is only accurate to with 15 milliseconds or so.

However, it's even worse: `System.currentTimeMillis()` measures *time since the Unix epoch* as measured by your system clock. So if you change the time on your computer (e.g. due to syncing your system clock to a time source, or due to a leap second, or any number of other things) then `currentTimeMillis()` can jump forward or backward arbitrarily large amounts of time.

If you want to measure **elapsed** time, **NEVER** use `currentTimeMillis()`. Use `System.nanoTime()` instead. As a bonus, on most systems, it's also substantially cheaper to invoke and substantially more accurate.

Comment: i have used System.nanoTime() which gives worse results than System.currentTimeMillis() . Some jobs even run for 0ms when System.nanoTime()  is used.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah When nano time has a resultion of 15ms as well, then jumping from 0 to 15 will happen at some point with that clock source. If you're unlucky it's the moment between recording startTime and checking in the loop. Results in effectively 0 wait time but there is nothing you could do about. Ps when testing `nanoTime`, you made sure to multiply your wait time by 1000000?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah: On Windows 8, `nanoTime()` should have substantially better resolution. Can you show the code where that's not the case?